# Microsoft Multi-factor Authentication not working with RDP

Tags: windows, security, login, azure

I am installing a new remote access server, where I need multi-factor authentication for RDP access (=a call back to the user's cell phone after they enter their credentials).  The problem is that the call back is not happening - they just get right in after entering their credentials.  If I click Test for one of the users under the Users section, the call-back happens just fine.

This is a new Windows 2008 R2 installation, with the latest version of the Multi-Factor Authentication Server (6.1.1).

The current / old remote access server is also Windows Server 2008 R2, running the older 5.0.9 authentication server.  Everything is working just fine there.

Some details:
Looking in the log files, I see this:
"Error connecting to Active Directory: Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest."

However, the same message is in the old server logs as well, where everything is working fine.  Also, there is no Active Directory at this company (they are mainly a Linux house).  I guess it could be that the new version does not work with local accounts, but I sure hope not!

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Just for completeness: Are you talking about the Remote Desktop Gateway service? Abd about Azure Multi Factor Authentication Server? Because I am looking into doing this without the Gateway, so that it also works in the local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376347.aspx) (updated last month), integration with AD is an option, which certainly sounds like it's not a requirement.

Have you gone through the configuration of the new one and ensured it's set up like the old one? What authentication method are you using on the old one, and is it set up the same way on the new one?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with this.  The servers are setup the same way - quite straightforward.  But I found the problem: earlier I had changed the computer name and then reinstalled the Multi-Factor Authentication Server.  Well, under the Windows Authentication area, the Applications tab, the server for Terminal Services was still set to the old computer name.  Must be cached somewhere.  After changing this and rebooting, it started working again.

Comment: Score! Glad to hear it.